# How to get through the whole list with if statement even if the first conditin was met?

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, if-statement

The code below is for a hangman game. When the `if` statement finds the first letter it stops and doesn't go further through the list, so it doesn't add the duplicates. For example, if a word contains two `a` letters, then it will only add the first one.

```
words = ["harry potter", "i love you forever", "neverland", "pockahontas"]
lives = 3
hangman = list(random.choice(words))
copy_of_hangman = hangman.copy()
print(copy_of_hangman)
for i in range(-6, 6, 2):
    copy_of_hangman[i] = "_"
print(copy_of_hangman)
while lives != 0:
    guess = input("Make your guess: ")
    for letter in hangman:
        if letter == guess:
            copy_of_hangman[hangman.index(letter)] = guess
            print(" ".join(copy_of_hangman))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a while loop.
So instead of `copy_of_hangman[hangman.index(letter)] = guess`
you can use something like (untested):

```
pos = hangman.index(letter)
while pos != None:
    copy_of_hangman[pos] = guess
    pos = hangman.index(letter)
```